# Errors related to discord.embed

Tags: python, discord

When I run the .py file, the window turns off immediately.
The error code did not appear at this time.
If I delete the code related to Embed, it will run normally.
I'm not sure what the problem is...

```
import discord, asyncio, os
from discord.ext import commands

token = "########"

game = discord.Game("&help")
bot =  commands.Bot(command_prefix = '&', status = discord.Status.online, activity = game)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("hi")

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title = "기억력이 나쁜 당신에게,,," , description=f"사용 방법을 알려드립니다.", color = 0x00ff56)
    embed.add_field(name="참가", value="&참가", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="멤버 제외", value="&제외", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="멤버 추가", value="&추가", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="참가자 명단", value="&명단", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="명단 초기화", value="&초기화", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="인원수 설정", value="&인원.", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="팀 생성", value="&생성", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="보이스 체널 이동", value="&보이스", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try another language than the Korean words, it may be the problem. try the english and see if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.

```
title = ""   ----->   title = f"" 
value = ""   ----->   value = f""
.
.
```

but I don't know why this works. :(

If anyone knows why, please let me know